# Java HashMap implementation has 'next' member in Entry class. What's the use of it

Tags: java, hashmap

Java HashMap implementation  has 'next' member in Entry private class.  Since, a new value for a key will override the old value, what's the use of 'next' member in the Entry  class.

```
static class Entry<K,V> implements Map.Entry<K,V> {
        final K key;
        V value;
        Entry<K,V> next;
        final int hash;

        /**
         * Creates new entry.
         */
        Entry(int h, K k, V v, Entry<K,V> n) {
            value = v;
            next = n;
            key = k;
            hash = h;
        }
   .....

}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`next` refers to the next entry in the same bucket.

You can have multiple entries in each bucket -- a bucket contains *all* the entries with hash code equal to some `i` mod 2^n for some `n`, not just the entry for one particular key.

Comment: ... because each bucket is implemented as a linked list

Comment: Thanks .. I understand that it's a linked list implementation.. But how can we get to all the values from the map .  We only get the last inserted one for the same key.

Comment: There is only one value per key.  The old values aren't left around in the map; that would be pointless.  But you can get the collection of values (one value per key, obviously) with `HashMap.values()`.

Comment: That's my point. When you can get only one value for a key, why do we have a reference to the old value. Can't we just discard it.

Comment: You don't have a reference to the old value.  `next` refers to an entry for a completely different key that happens to have the same hash code mod the size of the hash table.

Answer (score 2):

If more than one item hashes to the same bucket, then the bucket needs to be able to contain all the items, therefore in many implementations it'll become a collection of some sort, like a list.

Answer (score 0):

It is for linking entries together.